# It's now 2012. Can I start using CSS3 with wild abandon?

Tags: css

I'm developing a social media network, so the user base will hopefully be that of the average joe (not corporations). A lot of articles that date back to 2009 state that you shouldn't exlusively rely on CSS3 due to limited support. Is this still true today?

Comment: I should also state that I follow the 80/20 rule. If it satisfies 80 percent of the user base, I'm satisfied.

Comment: [If you can put up with the lack of support in IE6-8, then by all means use some of the strongly-supported stuff listed in this article.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-browser-support/)

Comment: Allriiight!! Another social media network. Just what we all need. Where do I sign up? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what browsers you want to support.  The question is a little too broad to answer directly because some CSS3 elements are more widely supported than others, which means you kind of need to take it on a case-by-case basis.

Check some sites like these before using various CSS3 elements:

http://caniuse.com/

http://html5please.com/

My overall advice is to use it! There are a lot of exciting and fun features, but just be aware of adding graceful degradation if you need to support some older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

"The future is already here — it's just not very evenly distributed."

-- [William Gibson](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/William_Gibson)

The answer is yes, no, and it depends.